# Too few arguments to function laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to query to db using two parameter which will be optional, so I defined a route as:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('question/{subject?}/{sbj_type?}', 'QuestionController@index')->name('question.index');
```

After that I made a function in **QuestionController.php** as:

```
public function index($subject = null, $sbj_type = null)
{
    $questions;
    if (!$subject) {
        dd($subject);
        if (!$sbj_type) {
            $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $subject, 'sbj_type_id' => $sbj_type])->get();
        }
        else {
            $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $subject])->get();
        }
    }
}
```

After that I inserted this **URL** as `http://localhost/digitalinvigilator/question?subject=1`
but I am getting null every time.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `question?subject=1` is definitely incorrect url. Your url should be `question/1`

Comment: it's an optional parameter, so I did that.

Comment: Optional parameter means that url can be either `question` or `question/1` or `question/1/2`.

Comment: Try Route::get('question/{:subject?}/{sbj_type?}', 'QuestionController@index')->name('question.index');

Comment: oh! is there any way to do it by `question?subject=1`

Comment: You can do this easily with $request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with $request

On your Route/Web.php

```
Route::get('question', 'QuestionController@index')->name('question.index');
```

On your controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
  $questions;
  if ($request->subject) {
    if (!$request->sbj_type) {
        $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $request->subject, 'sbj_type_id' => $request->sbj_type])->get();
    }
    else {
        $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $request->subject])->get();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have not a form through which I send Request can you elaborate why you used Request?

Comment: You can use $request on any through get and post method just try this dude and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have use `Request` to access query parameter.

```
public function index(Request $request, $subject = null, $sbj_type = null)
{
$questions;
if (!$request->has('subject)) {
    dd($subject);
    if (!$sbj_type) {
        $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $subject, 'sbj_type_id' => $sbj_type])->get();
    }
    else {
        $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $subject])->get();
    }
}
}
```

Condition can be different as per your requirement in `If`

Comment: I have not a form through which I send **Request** can you elaborate why you used Request?

Comment: Does not matter if you are not using form, query parameter can be access by ```Request```. and if you do not want to use ```Request``` send ```subject``` data as ```Route Parameter```

Answer (score 0):

To use it like you specify, you have to use the `query` method on the `Request` object.

You also have a bug in your first if, you check for `$subject` being a falsy value. So if `!$subject` is true, it will continue so your `dd($subject)` will always output `null` or a falsy value. So use it like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $questions;
    if ($request->query('subject')) {
        dd($subject);
        if ($request->query('sbj_type')) {
            $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $request->query('subject'), 'sbj_type_id' => $request->query('sbj_type')])->get();
        } else {
            $questions = Question::where(['subject_id' => $request->query('subject'))->get();
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input